# Is it OK to extend furnace gas pipe to the other side of the house (traversal) to connect a barbeque?

Tags: natural-gas, fitting

I am doing some reno work and I will be opening up the ceiling above an area that would be traversed by an extension of the gas pipe if that could be used to feed a barbeque (winter time and summer time). The barbeque is outdoor and used on ocassions for certain dishes that require this.

The pipe will traverse the house in the middle (along the short side of a square shape bungallow) I would open an outlet there where I could connect a rubber gas pipe the same way I currently connect the barbeque to the propane tank

Is such an extension allowed?
Is using that rubber pipe OK (it will not be in the way) to use summer or winter?

Comment: you can't just replace propane with NG, it will burn far too hot and your meat will be carbon. it can usually be converted, but don't skip that step.

Comment: good point, I did not realize that , my focus was piping here :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Is such an extension allowed?"

That's entirely up to at least two entities that "the internet" has no particular way of knowing about, but you do. Call them.

1. Your gas company (and that may involve an assesment of whether the
   furnace pipe is of adequate size to feed both appliances, or not)
2. Your "Local Authority Having Jurisdiction" or LAHJ - town/city/county/state may have a dim view of DIY gas piping, or they may merely require that your gas company bless it before commissioning, or they may not give a fig - though the last is uncommon in LAHJs with piped gas. Your gas supplier may be helpful in telling you who you need to call locally.

Comment: well I guess my question was referring more to the technical obstacles. #1 being one of them and the other any issues that could weather could cause to exposed gas pipes, metal or rubber

Answer (score 1):

It may be permitted but I would ( and did ) permanently mount the grill and use flexible metal ( stainless ) connector at the grill. I used 1/2 in. pipe ( about a 40 ft. run) and it had the capacity for a grill with five burners, no problem. I have nat gas but propane volume would be less for the same BTU/heat.